Java freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException
Всем привет. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Есть простенькое приложение на Java Spring. Рега, логинка, создание заявки и просмотр своих заявок.
Контроллер раз:
@PostMapping("/feedback")
    public String submitFeedback(
            @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,
            @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName,
            @RequestParam("message") String message,
            Model model) {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof MyUserDetails userDetails) {
            FeedbackModel feedback = new FeedbackModel();
            feedback.setFirstName(firstName);
            feedback.setLastName(lastName);
            feedback.setMessage(message);
            feedback.setStatus("В очереди");

            UserModel user = new UserModel();
            user.setId(userDetails.getId());
            feedback.setUserModel(user);
            feedbackRepository.save(feedback);
            return "redirect:/my-requests";
        }

Контроллер два:
@GetMapping("/my-requests")
    public String viewMyRequests(Model model) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof MyUserDetails userDetails) {
            List<FeedbackModel> feedbacks = feedbackRepository.findByUserModelId(userDetails.getId());
            model.addAttribute("feedbacks", feedbackRepository.findByUserModelId(userDetails.getId()));
            return "my-requests"; 
        }

        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Пользователь не аутентифицирован.");
        return "redirect:/feedback";
    }

Шаблон my-requests.ftlh
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Мои заявки | Bank Support</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            color: #333;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #d32f2f;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .container {
            padding: 20px;
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .requests-table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .requests-table th, .requests-table td {
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .requests-table th {
            background-color: #d32f2f;
            color: white;
        }
        .requests-table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .back-btn {
            display: block;
            margin: 20px auto;
            text-align: center;
            color: #d32f2f;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        footer {
            background-color: #d32f2f;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Bank Support</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Мои заявки</h2>
    <table class="requests-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Имя</th>
                <th>Фамилия</th>
                <th>Сообщение</th>
                <th>Статус заявки</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <#list feedbacks as feedback>
                <tr>
                    <td>${feedback.id}</td>
                    <td>${feedback.firstName}</td>
                    <td>${feedback.lastName}</td>
                    <td>${feedback.message?no_esc}</td>
                    <td>${feedback.status}</td>
                </tr>
            </#list>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="back-btn" onclick="location.href='/feedback'">Вернуться к отправке заявки</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Так же БД на постгре c такой структурой
bank=# \dt
          List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  |  Owner   
--------+----------+-------+----------
 public | app_user | table | postgres
 public | feedback | table | postgres
(2 rows)

bank=# select * from app_user;
 is_admin | id |        email        |                           password                           ----------+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
        1 |  1 | admin@bank.com | <password_hash>
        0 |  2 | qwe@qwe.qwe         | <password_hash>
(2 rows)

bank=# select * from feedback;
 id | user_id | first_name | last_name |         message         |  status   
----+---------+------------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------
  1 |       1 | admin      | admin     | test                    | В очереди
  2 |       2 | asd        | asd       | sad                     | В очереди
(2 rows)

суть в чем, ЛОКАЛЬНО при подъеме постгри и сервера, всё работает отлично, GET на /my-requests работает, заявки рендерятся. Но при заворачивании приложения в докер композ, при всё том же GET на /my-requests в поле <td>${feedback.id}</td> появляется ошибка freemaker'а
FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> feedback.id [in template "my-requests.ftlh" at line 80, column 27] ---- Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it. ---- Tip: If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)?? ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${feedback.id} [in template "my-requests.ftlh" at line 80, column 25] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:134) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToTextualCommon(EvalUtil.java:486) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:406) at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToStringOrMarkup(EvalUtil.java:375) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.calculateInterpolatedStringOrMarkup(DollarVariable.java:104) at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:63) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:380) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executedNestedContentForCollOrSeqListing(IteratorBlock.java:321) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedContent(IteratorBlock.java:271) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:244) at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:654) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:108) at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:344) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:350) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:323) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:383) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:365) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:298) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:252) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:181) at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1432) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1168) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:362) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:278) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Разумеется различные мисконфиги докер композа проверял, всё хорошо, т.к заявки и пользователи создаются в БД
Как это выглядит на фронте
В докере:

Локально:


А где сам docker-compose.yml?

похоже что через докер не все переменные видны, в ошибке сказано что feedback не инициализирована или не видит поле id
